# Multiple Backbone.Routers and the default route -- order of matching routes/loading routers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, marionette

Application that i'm coding is getting bigger and bigger and so far i've been using just one router for everything. I wanted to split it into two separate routers (for starters, more coming of course) like this:

```
class window.UFO.Routers.App extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    #root
    ''                         : 'root'
    #not found
    '*notFound'                : 'notFound'

class window.UFO.Routers.Companies extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'companies/new/:angellist' : 'companiesNew'
    'companies/new'            : 'companiesNew'
    'companies/:id/edit'       : 'companiesEdit'
    'companies/:id/edit/people': 'companiesPeople'
    'companies/:id/edit/people/:preselect': 'companiesPeople'
```

There is an issue though: notFound route is triggered every time i try to access one of companies routes. I'm guessing it's because App router is loaded and initailized first (i'm using rails asset pipeline).

Do you know any workaround for this problem? Maybe a way to force Backbone to check all available routers before matching to *notFound route?

btw. we are using Backbone.Marionette, so solutions may use tools and code from it.

Comment: as i see from source code http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html , routes are checked in the order they are initialized, so try to load and initialize App router last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlad Niktin's comment has lead me in correct direction. However, actual url matching order is reverse of router initialization order. So, to make sure that '*notFound' route is matched last you have to load App router very first.

My code, using Marionette initializers:

```
window.APP.addInitializer ->

  appRouter = new window.APP.Routers.App

  companiesRouter = new window.APP.Routers.Companies
  sessionsRouter = new window.APP.Routers.Sessions
  roundsRouter = new window.APP.Routers.Rounds
```

I'm still not sure if that's the optimal solution as you always have to remember to add another line to this initializer for each new router.

Answer (score 0):

I like to declare routes in the same files as my controllers, and I *don't* like to have to explicitly order my controller file includes.

So, here's an alternative way to make sure routes are ordered by specificity:

https://gist.github.com/chrisdavies/b56d1011cd9ca9394d86

(Basically, it stores routes in an array, then sorts them with `*` on top, followed by `:` followed by explicit routes like `users/new`. If a route has two `:` characters, it will be included before routes with only one.